# Change thumbnail and input text on selection of option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a URL and a thumbnail of a website depending on what the sure selects in the pull down menu. I don't want them to have to click a button, just select it and it change the image and URL in the text box. I have code here but it's not changing anything. Any help would be great.

My Code is all in one: (I am using social media icons for this example)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change_image() {
   var select = document.getElementById('my_images');
   var selection = select.selectedIndex;
   var img = select.options[selection].value;   
   src = img;
}

function change_text() {
   var select = document.getElementById('my_images');
   var selection = select.selectedIndex;
   var text = select.options[selection].id;   
   value = text;
}
</script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <img id="change_this_src" src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/176530/file-18534154-jpg/images/facebook_icon_small.jpg">
 <input type="text" id="change_this_text" value="" />

<form>
<select onchange="change_image(); change_text();" id='my_images'>
   <option id="http://example.com?p=1!1044" value="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/176530/file-18534154-jpg/images/facebook_icon_small.jpg">Facebook
   <option id="http://example.com?p=2!1044" value="http://ua-mac.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Twitter-5.7-for-iOS-app-icon-small.png">Twitter
   <option id="http://example.com?p=3!1044" value="http://reikisanjeevani.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Skype-icon_small.png">Skype
<select>
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tagged JQuery. This needs to be pure JS or can be done via JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Find your Updated Fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ofvoerh2/1/)**.

You have just to assign `src` to your `img` tag :

```
 $('#change_this_src').attr('src', src); //Assigning src to the image
```

And assign `value` to the `input` tag :

```
 $('#change_this_text').val(value); //Assigning value to the input
```

**Full JS :**

```
change_image = function() {
   var select = document.getElementById('my_images');
   var selection = select.selectedIndex;
   var img = select.options[selection].value;   
   src = img;

   $('#change_this_src').attr('src', src);  //Assigning src to the image
}

change_text = function () {
   var select = document.getElementById('my_images');
   var selection = select.selectedIndex;
   var text = select.options[selection].id;   
   value = text;

   $('#change_this_text').val(value); //Assigning value to the input
}
```

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've sepparated your script from your html.
Now when the select changes both image and text change accordingly

***!** `<option>` and `<select>` tags weren't  closed

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/n1durfar/)**

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  $('img').attr('src', $(this).val());
  $('input[type=text]').val($('option:selected').text() + ' ID: ' + $('option:selected').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="change_this_src" src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/176530/file-18534154-jpg/images/facebook_icon_small.jpg">
<input type="text" id="change_this_text" value="" />
<form>
  <select id='my_images'>
    <option id="http://example.com?p=1!1044" value="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/176530/file-18534154-jpg/images/facebook_icon_small.jpg">Facebook</option>
    <option id="http://example.com?p=2!1044" value="http://ua-mac.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Twitter-5.7-for-iOS-app-icon-small.png">Twitter</option>
    <option id="http://example.com?p=3!1044" value="http://reikisanjeevani.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Skype-icon_small.png">Skype</option>
  </select>
</form>
```